# How to change Verify account email template which triggers on new user creation action

Tags: apex, email, email-template

When a new user is created in salesforce a verification email is getting triggered to verify the email ID. This is working perfectly fine but we are not able to see the related email template that is coming as an email.[image]

We are looking to change/do few modifications for rebranding this welcome message.Tried in all ways to check the templates but couldn't figure it out. Is there any way to change this or will this be a default action triggered by salesforce and where there is no scope for customization.

Comment: I think this is Salesforce's template. We can't change. We can change template for portals and community users.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating Community user then you can change the email format, but for standard user [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KCKTAA4) implies it is not possible to change the layout.

> Enhancement: Allow customizable email template for new user account & password reset email notification. If no custom template is selected, the system should default to standard SFDC template.

As for Community Users, from the Community Docs Point 6:

> Use the default email templates or use the lookups to select different
>   templates for welcome emails to new community members, forgotten
>   password emails, and notification emails about reset passwords.
>
> If you customize the contents of an email template, we recommend that
>   you use the {!Community_Url} merge field.
>
> WelcomeEmailTemplateId—ID of the email template used when sending
>   welcome emails to new community members.

[Customize Email Sent from Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_customize_email.htm)

There is an Idea for the standard user Email templates which you can upvote here

[customize email template for new user account & password reset email notificatio](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KCKTAA4)

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have added for the community docs. For Idea I am not sure if we need here. Please confirm and Thanks for suggestion.